# What is the difference between a Iterable and a Collection in ImmutableJS

Tags: immutable.js

I have read the docs, yet the difference between those two is not clear to me (especially since they share lot of the same operators)

It would be also great to see some examples explaining the difference. Is one more "common" than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Collection` extends `Iterable`, so it's fair to say, that every `Collection` instance is also `Iterable`.

`Collection` can be viewed at as a materialized, finite set of data. On top of `Iterable` interface it defines methods and members such as `size`, `last`, `equals` and 'hashCode`.

`Iterable` means something you can iterate through. On the top of `Collections`, this includes lazily generated sequences (which are possibly infinite! For example `immutable.Repeat` is capable of constructing infinite seuqences.). For this reason, `size`, `last`, does not make much sense here, `equals` and `hashCode` would be really tricky and probably not worth it.